# Getting WebSphere MQ message headers

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to list the headers of a message. But when I use the code provided by the IBM the loop is never entered:

```
...
int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);
...
MQMessage rcvMessage = new MQMessage();
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
queue.get(rcvMessage, gmo);
MQHeaderIterator it = new MQHeaderIterator(rcvMessage);
   while (it.hasNext()) {
      MQHeader header = it.nextHeader();
      System.out.println("Header type " + header.type() + ": " + header);
   }
...
```

Has anyone any idea where my mistake is?

Here is a message read with `qload`:

```
A VER 2
A RPT 0
A MST 8
A EXP -1
A FDB 0
A ENC 273
A CCS 819
A FMT
A PRI 0
A PER 0
A MSI 414D5120574D42514D3144312020202035E2165414530020
A COI 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
A BOC 0
A RTQ
A RTM WMBQM1D1
A USR lanes
A ACC 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
A AID
A PAT 28
A PAN mq.MQ
A PTD 20140916
A PTT 11415704
A AOD
A GRP 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
A MSQ 1
A OFF 0
A MSF 0
A ORL -1
X 000D48656C6C6F2C20576F726C6421
```

Comment: Are you sure there are message headers? Is there a message body, in fact?

Comment: Yes, I yust put a message with a payload of "hello world" on the queue. I can read the message with `qload` and see the headers.

Comment: what specific headers are you seeing? MQMD isn't classed as a 'header'. That code will only show things like the RFH2

Comment: So this seems to be my mistake! But how do I access the Reply To Queue Manager for example? Am I supposed to open a new question for that?

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what you want to do, i.e. you want to access the Reply To Queue Manager in the MQMD of your message.

Comment: @Calanais: your comment is the answer! I will open a new question for the MQMDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calanais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332076/calanais) gave the answer: the message descriptors aren't classed as header.

Here is a [table](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1001_xiao/1001_xiao.html) of headers:

```
Header  Header Description  Format Name

MQCIH   CICS information header MQFMT_CICS
MQDLH   Dead-letter header  MQFMT_DEAD_LETTER_HEADER
MQDH    Distribution-list header    MQFMT_DIST_HEADER
MQEPH   Embedded PCF header MQFMT_EMBEDDED_PCF
MQIIH   IMS information header  MQFMT_IMS
MQMDE   Message-descriptor extension    MQFMT_MD_EXTENSION
MQCFH   PCF header  MQFMT_ADMIN / MQFMT_EVENT / MQFMT_PCF
MQRMH   Reference message header    MQFMT_REF_MSG_HEADER
MQRFH   Formatting header   MQFMT_RF_HEADER
MQRFH2  Version-2 rules and formatting header   MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2
MQWIH   Work information header MQFMT_WORK_INFO_HEADER
MQXQH   Transmission queue header   MQFMT_XMIT_Q_HEADER
```

If you want to read the **MQMD fields** see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906676/how-to-read-values-out-of-the-websphrere-mq-mqmd-header-with-the-ibm-mq-librarie).