# How to read values out of the WebSphrere MQ MQMD header with the IBM MQ libraries

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Let's take this code snippet as a starting point:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
...
int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);
...
MQMessage rcvMessage = new MQMessage();
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
queue.get(rcvMessage, gmo);
```

Now I want to get the message type and the reply to queue manager for example. It can't be too hard but I did not find anything on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the JavaDoc for the MQMessage class (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMessage.html)

it extends the MQMD class (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMD.html)

and this has all the MQMD values on it.. so this code for example will show you the replyTo & type values

```
  System.out.println("MsgType="+ rcvMessage.messageType);
  System.out.println("ReplyToQ="+ rcvMessage.replyToQueueName);
  System.out.println("ReplyToQmgr="+ rcvMessage.replyToQueueManagerName);
```